# Unable to install VS Code in Anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I just downloaded Anaconda and I would like to install VS Code from the Navigator.

I clicked on `Install`, and then I have the loading wheel for few seconds, and then nothing. The `Install` button turns green again, instead of changing to `Launch`:

before:
[image]

during:
[image]

After:
[image]

There is no error messages to explain me what is the problem.

I'm working on Windows 10 64 bits.

How can I install VS Code from Anaconda ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know why the Navigator isn't installing VSCode, however would installing it 'the normal way' be an option? I.e. go to https://code.visualstudio.com/ than download and install it.

Comment: Even if I installed VS Code with "the normal way" and then I open Anaconda, the button is still `Install` green

Comment: Right, but why do you need to launch it from the Navigator? As far as your original problem is concerned: depending on where Anaconda is installed and what VSCode does during setup, you might have to launch Navigator with elevated privileges. I.e. right-click on a Navigator shortcut, select "Run as administrator" and try to install VSCode from there again if you really need it inside Navigator. (this is just an educated guess)

Comment: It doesn't change anything if i run Anaconda as administrator. I need to Install (or at least launch) VS Code from Anaconda to work with python in VS Code with all library preloaded with Anaconda

Comment: When you launch VSCode, go to the Extensions tab on the left side, make sure the Python extension is installed. Once it's installed you'll see something similar to `Python 3.7.4 64-bit` at the bottom of the VSCode window. Click on it and select `Python X.X.X 64-bit ('base': conda)` from the dropdown. You can now use your Anaconda packages in VSCode.

Comment: Specifically that copy of VS Code installs is the [Anaconda extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.anaconda-extension-pack) which you can install manually.

Comment: @BrettCannon Hm, I didn't know that Navigator's VSCode automatically installs the Anaconda extension pack. However all that does is install the Python extension (the one I mentioned) and the YAML extension (which is useful but not required I would guess). Wether you install the Python or the Anaconda extension shouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: @iAmoric correct, just being specific about how one can download and install VS Code themselves and get the exact same extensions out of the box.

Comment: Same issue today. I normally just update it via Anaconda...today, I'm getting the same issue mentioned in the Q above. I think the reason for using Anaconda install is that it comes prepackaged with some main libraries (I could be wrong). This is the time that I miss Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It only worked appropriately when I used **install for all users**  and kept the default location. Neither a custom location with no spaces nor an installation on a default location on **current user only** worked. I would suggest you try that, Install for all users on the default location (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you have installed VS Code externally.
2. Open VS Code, click "Extensions" on left-side of the panel.
3. Ensure "Anaconda Extension Pack" is installed, if not, install it first.
4. After finished installing "Anaconda Extension Pack", close VS Code.
5. Open Anaconda Navigator using Administrator rights.
6. VS Code should be in Home, under Applications on "base (root)". If not, click "Refresh" button on right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

I found I didn't have to "install for all users" as GeorgeRob suggests above, I only had to first install VS Code (which is a separate source-code editor from Microsoft that's absolutely free), then install the "Extension for Anaconda" found within VS Code (you can find and select it from the Extensions menu which can be found on the far left side of the Welcome Page and symbolized by an icon composed of four squares with one detached), and THEN AND ONLY THEN install Anaconda. The missing tile finally appeared after those two preparatory steps!